# Create dir structure base of creation date of file

Tags: bash

I am working on bash script to create dir structure base on the date file createed, like for 2019-03-14 dir structure look like /test/data/2019/03/14 and for second file create dir structure to create /test/data/2019/01/01 and so on.
Currently I have thousand of files, so base on creation date it create a dir structure and move file to its' location.

- -rw-r-----   3 usermq hadoop     460373 2019-03-14 10:21 /data/sample/zip/samele_732503e.zip

  -rw-r-----   3 usermq hadoop     534677 2019-01-01 10:21 /data/sample/zip/sample_16d7dd1.zip

This is what I have so far

```
source_dir=/data/sample/zip
target_dir=/data/new_location
## This is giving me file name
hdfs dfs -ls "${source_dir}/*.zip" | awk '{print $8}'  | while read FILE; do
## This is giving me create date
hdfs dfs -ls "${source_dir}/*.zip" | awk '{print $5}'  | while read CR_DATE; do

FILENAME="$(basename "${FILE}")"

FILE_YEAR="$(echo "${CR_DATE}" | cut --bytes=01-04)"
FILE_MONTH="$(echo "${CR_DATE}" | cut --bytes=06-07)"
FILE_DAY="$(echo "${CR_DATE}" | cut --bytes=09-10)" 
REPORT_DIR="${target_dir}/year=${FILE_YEAR}/month=${FILE_MONTH}/day=${FILE_DATE}"    

$(hdfs dfs -test -e ${REPORT_DIR})
if [[ "$?" -eq "1" ]]; then
     $(hdfs dfs  -mkdir -p "${REPORT_DIR}")
fi

hdfs dfs -mv "${FILE}" "${REPORT_DIR}"
```

- Not sure how to look through with these two values "FILE" and
  "CR_DATE" and first create dir first /data/new_location/2019/03/14/
- Then move file from source_dir=/data/sample/zip to
  /data/new_location/2019/03/14/

Comment: Just a quick question here, but what did you try so far to solve this conundrum?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

base_dir=/home/user/data # the path to the directory

for file in "$base_dir"/sample/zip/*.zip;do
        dir="$(stat -c %x $file|cut -d' ' -f1)"
        mkdir -p "$base_dir/${dir//-//}"
        cp -v "$file" "$base_dir/${dir//-//}"
done
```

Comment: your code could be correct local file system, it is not working for me since files are located at HDFS location, in order to see files in base_dir, I need to use hdfs dfs -ls dir location where the files are, my above code is need some modification to capture date and corresponding file in loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is small modification to my above code, it is working

```
#!/bin/bash

source_dir=/data/sample/zip
target_dir=/data/new_location
## This is giving you creation date and file name
hdfs dfs -ls "${source_dir}/*.zip" | awk '{print $6 "-" $8}'  | while read FILE; do
FILENAME="$(basename "${FILE}")"

FILE_YEAR="$(echo "${FILE}" | cut --bytes=01-04)"
FILE_MONTH="$(echo "${FILE}" | cut --bytes=06-07)"
FILE_DAY="$(echo "${FILE}" | cut --bytes=09-10)"

REPORT_DIR="${target_dir}/year=${FILE_YEAR}/month=${FILE_MONTH}/day=${FILE_DATE}"    

$(hdfs dfs -test -e ${REPORT_DIR})
if [[ "$?" -eq "1" ]]; then
   $(hdfs dfs  -mkdir -p "${REPORT_DIR}")
fi


hdfs dfs -mv "${source_dir}/${FILENAME}" "${REPORT_DIR}"

done
```